# Post method webservice call for rpgle program

Tags: post, methods, rpgle

Please help me resolve this issue.

I have written post method web service program in rpgle. I will receive xml input for purchase order. If process success means , i should return Acknowledgement as a xml response. Here my problem is, i have declared item data structure as a array with dim(9). so if item blank also , web service generating xml for blanks items . i don't know how to control.
 is there any other way to control in program or in web service deployment ?. please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<WBSRVGET5Result>
    <BROKERACKNOWLEDGEMENT>
        <IDENTIFICATION>
            <DATE>2017-06-12T08:33:25</DATE>
            <FROMORG_ID>xxxxx</FROMORG_ID>
            <MESSAGEPROTOCOL_ID>PurchaseOrder</MESSAGEPROTOCOL_ID>
            <SENDERORG_ID>xxxxx</SENDERORG_ID>
            <TOORG_ID>Vendor Name here</TOORG_ID>
        </IDENTIFICATION>
        <ORDERHEADER>
            <ACKNOWLEDGEMENTTYPE></ACKNOWLEDGEMENTTYPE>
            <BACKORDEROK>0</BACKORDEROK>
            <BROKERCREATEDDATE>2017-06-09</BROKERCREATEDDATE>
            <BROKERORDERID>09442000</BROKERORDERID>
            <CUSTOMERPONUMBER>997545</CUSTOMERPONUMBER>
            <FREIGHTPAYMENTMETHOD>P</FREIGHTPAYMENTMETHOD>
            <OVERALLPROCESSSTATUS>P</OVERALLPROCESSSTATUS>
            <REQUESTEDSHIPDATE>2017-08-21</REQUESTEDSHIPDATE>
            <SHIPMETHOD>90</SHIPMETHOD>
            <SHIPPINGINSTRUCTIONS></SHIPPINGINSTRUCTIONS>
            <SUBSTITUTIONOK>0</SUBSTITUTIONOK>
            <VENDORNUMBER>0090000484</VENDORNUMBER>
            <VENDORORDERID></VENDORORDERID>
            <SOLDTO>
                <SOLDTOADDRESS1>PO BOX 808</SOLDTOADDRESS1>
                <SOLDTOADDRESS2></SOLDTOADDRESS2>
                <SOLDTOCITY>WABASSO</SOLDTOCITY>
                <SOLDTOCONTACTNAME>SHIR BARTON</SOLDTOCONTACTNAME>
                <SOLDTOCOUNTRY>(77</SOLDTOCOUNTRY>
                <SOLDTOEMAIL></SOLDTOEMAIL>
                <SOLDTOFAX>(772)589-5019</SOLDTOFAX>
                <SOLDTONAME>CITY DSP</SOLDTONAME>
                <SOLDTOPHONE>(772)589-5835</SOLDTOPHONE>
                <SOLDTOSTATE>FL</SOLDTOSTATE>
                <SOLDTOZIP>32970</SOLDTOZIP>
            </SOLDTO>
            <SHIPTO>
                <BROKERSHIPTONUMBER>66981</BROKERSHIPTONUMBER>
                <SHIPTOADDRESS1>9080 N US 1</SHIPTOADDRESS1>
                <SHIPTOADDRESS2></SHIPTOADDRESS2>
                <SHIPTOCITY>WABASSO</SHIPTOCITY>
                <SHIPTOCONTACTNAME>ROCKURS LDSP</SHIPTOCONTACTNAME>
                <SHIPTOCOUNTRY>US</SHIPTOCOUNTRY>
                <SHIPTOEMAIL>grower.com</SHIPTOEMAIL>
                <SHIPTOFAX>(772)589-5019</SHIPTOFAX>
                <SHIPTONAME>ROCK CITY NURS LDSP</SHIPTONAME>
                <SHIPTOPHONE>(772)589-5835</SHIPTOPHONE>
                <SHIPTOSTATE>FL</SHIPTOSTATE>
                <SHIPTOZIP>32970</SHIPTOZIP>
            </SHIPTO>
        </ORDERHEADER>
        <ORDERDETAILS>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO>10</BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO>4091391972084</BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY>168.0</CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION>EVOLVU BLUED 84/84 Tray</MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY>168.0</ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>2017-08-21</SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO>4091391972084</VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO>11</BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO>4091391972083</BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY>128.0</CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION>EVOLD 84/84 Tray</MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY>128.0</ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>2017-08-21</SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO>4091391972084</VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO>12</BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO>4091391972085</BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY>198.0</CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION>EVOIND 84/84 Tray</MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY>198.0</ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>2017-09-15</SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO>4091391972084</VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <BROKERLINEITEMNO></BROKERLINEITEMNO>
                <BROKERMATERIALNO></BROKERMATERIALNO>
                <COMMITTEDINVPONO></COMMITTEDINVPONO>
                <CONFIRMEDQTY></CONFIRMEDQTY>
                <LINEITEMCOMM></LINEITEMCOMM>
                <LINEITEMSTATUS></LINEITEMSTATUS>
                <MATERIALDESCRIPTION></MATERIALDESCRIPTION>
                <ORDERQTY></ORDERQTY>
                <SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE></SCHEDULEDSHIPDATE>
                <VENDORMATERIALNO></VENDORMATERIALNO>
            </ITEM>
        </ORDERDETAILS>
    </BROKERACKNOWLEDGEMENT>
</WBSRVGET5Result>
```

Comment: How are you implementing the web service? Are you using the `Integrated Web Services for i` server or something else?

Comment: Yes. Using integrated web services . Restful method

Answer (score 0):

If it's a IAS - you should add extra out parameters (INT) names as a you table + '_LENGTH' 
In your case it;s somethink like this:

```
dcl-ds ORDERDETAILS;
  ITEM_LENGTH int(10); 
  ITEM likeds(XYZ) dim(9);
end-ds;
```

ITEM_LENGTH must be before ITEM definition :)

You don't see this variable in response of web service - but you see only ITEM_LENGTH element's on response :)